# using mongodb+srv to connect to mongodb deployed as a statefulset

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I have deployed a 3 pod mongodb statefulset in kubernetes and I am attempting to use the new `mongodb+srv` connection string (mongodb 3.6) to connect to the headless k8s service that has the SRV records for the cluster members.

However, the connection is failing as follows (the mongo command is being executed on the first pod in the satefulset):

```
root@mongodb-0:/# mongo "mongodb+srv://mongodb-headless.mongo.svc.cluster.local"
FailedToParse: Hostname mongodb-0.mongodb-headless.mongo.svc.cluster.local. is not within the domain mongo.svc.cluster.local
try 'mongo --help' for more information
```

Here is the headless service configuration:

```
kubectl describe svc/mongodb-headless -n mongo
Name:              mongodb-headless
Namespace:         mongo
Labels:            app=mongodb-headless
                   chart=mongodb-1.0.1
                   heritage=Tiller
                   release=mongo
Annotations:       service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints=true
Selector:          app=mongodb,release=mongo
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                None
Port:              mongodb  27017/TCP
TargetPort:        27017/TCP
Endpoints:         
192.168.16.8:27017,192.168.208.3:27017,192.168.64.9:27017
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

The mongodb cluster is functional and I can connect to the members over localhost or using a separate (non-headless) service (e.g. `mongo "mongodb://mongodb.mongo.svc.cluster.local"`).

Am I missing something in the `mongodb+srv` requirements/implementation or do I need to adjust something in my k8s deployment?

Comment: You will want to ensure the `Service` name matches what the `StatefulSet` is expecting (which, as you saw it the working URL, is very likely `mongodb`); you can confirm what the `StatefulSet` wants via `kubectl -n mongo get -o yaml sts mongodb` and look for `serviceName:`

Comment: The service name in the stateful set matches the name of the headless serice, the statefulset itself works as expected and `nslookup` as well as  `kubectl describe svc/mongodb-headless -n mongo` produce correct hostname to IP address mapping. It seems to me that the processing of the `mongodb+srv` style connection string is not handling correctly the results of the queries against the kubernetes DNS.

Comment: @BostonHiker, I'm facing the same issue, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

The connections of `mongodb+srv://` [use SSL/TLS by default](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.tls). You need to disable them manually by adding `tls=false` or `ssl=false`.

The following connection URI works for me on a MongoDB 4.2 three members replica set on GKE.

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://svc-headless.my-namespace.cluster.local/?tls=false&ssl=false"
```

Add `replicaSet` query option may help to connect to the right replica set.

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://svc-headless.my-namespace.cluster.local/?tls=false&ssl=false&replicaSet=rs0"
```